# Using `\left(`, `\right)` across multiple lines in ConTeXt formula

Tags: math-mode, context

I wanted to give ConTeXt a try, but I am stuck with a problem in the formula environment.
I have an mathematical expression across multiple lines that I want to wrap in nicely sized parentheses. How do I do that with ConTeXt?

In Latex there are some workarounds where you manually size the brackets with `\bigg(`.
Or you can use `\left(` followed by `\right.` in the same line.

But I don't know how I would do that in ConTeXt. My bad workaround would be to use `\text{\tfd (}`, but if there are parentheses on the line with `\left( ... \right)` as well, they are larger than the `\tfd (` version.

**Example:**

```
\startformula \startalign
\NC \frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x} = \NC \text{\tfd (} \left(\frac{k}{x}\right) \NR
\NC \NC + y \text{\tfd )} \NR
\stopalign \stopformula
```

Comment: Why can't you use `\right.`, `\bigg(` and friends with ConTeXt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual scaling of delimiters works with ConTeXt as well:

```
\starttext
\startformula \startalign
\NC \frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x} = \NC \biggl( \left(\frac{k}{x}\right) \NR
\NC \NC + y \biggr) \NR
\stopalign \stopformula
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Are there also `\biggl` and `\biggr` or does ConTeXt guess the right side automatically?

Comment: I haven't looked at the internal code in a while, but I don't think that ConTeXt does anything different from plain TeX here. So, if these need to be `\biggl` and `\biggr` in plain, then the same is needed in ConTeXt

Comment: Well, they *do* need to be `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`, then.